# Independence of discrete random variable

Tags: probability, generating-functions, independence

Let $U_i$,$V_i,\ i=1,\dots,n$ be $2n$ real random variables i.i.d..

Are $(U_i-V_i)^2,\ i=1,\dots, n$ independent ?

---

I should check that

$$P((U_i-V_i)^2=k,(U_i-V_i)^2=p)=P((U_i-V_i)^2=k)P((U_j-V_j)^2=p)$$

is there any general theorem about such independence or should I use generating function to make the computation ?

Comment: If $(U_i ,V_i)$ is independent of $(U_j, V_j)$ then any function of $(U_i, V_i)$ is also independent of a function of $(U_j, V_j)$. So in your case, yes they are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think theorem 2.1.10 of [Rick Durret's Probability: Theory and Examples](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) is what you are looking for.